# Conjecture regarding alternating infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Conjecture:** There do not exist functions $f, g : \mathbb N \to \mathbb R^+$ and $c \in \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ such that simultaneously

- $S_0=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1 )^n}{f(n)} = 0$
- $S_1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1 )^n}{f(n)}*g(n)^c = 0$
- $S_2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1 )^n}{f(n)}*\frac{1}{g(n)^c} = 0$

It seems correct but I could not find a proof or counterexample to this. Can anyone please help?

As pointed out if $g(n)=1$ then its trivial. Thus, we are concerned where $|g(n)^c| \neq |\frac{1}{g(n)^c}|$.

Comment: What about $g(n)=1$?

Comment: I was going to add that one trivial case not allowed. :) updating.

Comment: $n\in\mathbb{N}$, no?

Comment: Similarly, what about $g(n)$ is a constant itself?

Comment: yes. typo error.

Comment: we are ruling out all such trivial cases. For example, $c>0$ be some polynomial.

Comment: $f,g$ are complex-valued? Or in positive reals?

Comment: For the constants $n∈N, c∈R$. As far as the functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ go, both can be assumed to be in real domain, not necessarily positive reals though. So, we are not considering complex numbers here.

Comment: Please accept my apologies, as my for background is in C.S. not mathematics. What i meant by $g()$ is some function that takes an positive integer $n$ as a parameter, thus $g(n)$ represents the result, which can be any real number possible depending on the function. Similarly for $f(n)$. Please, feel free to edit it if you feel it can be clearer.

Comment: I edited the question, feel free to review my edit or rollback if I misunderstood you.

Comment: its fine. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(n)=n^n$ for odd $n$ and $(n-1)^{(n-1)}$ for even $n$. Every second term in $f(n)$ is the same and hence the summation converges to $0$. Now let $g(n)=2$.

Obviously both summation converge to $0$ as they are a constant multiple of the summation of all $\frac{1}{f(n)}$. This disproves the original statement.

Comment: do they both converge to 0?

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected it.

Comment: The original poster stated that $g(n)$ is a constant cannot be allowed because of triviality.

Comment: The post states "we are concerned where $|g^c(n)|\ne |\frac{1}{g^c(n)}|$" which for this chosen function is true.

Comment: Thank you but If we were to assume $g(n)$ as some constant $k$, then it amounts to multiplying the series $S_0$ or 0 with $k^c$ and $1/k^c$ respectively. And that is obviously 0. Thus, we are ignoring all such trivial cases.

Comment: $g(n)$ being nonconstant is not really a restiction. Peter Foreman's example works just as well when we only impose $g(2n+1) = g(2n+2)$ for all $n$.

Comment: I understood. But, as the example states: "Let $f(n)=n^n$ for odd $n$ and $(n−1)^(n−1)$ for even n." It seems technically they are two definitions of the function $f(n)$ as I don't see how plugging in a value of $n$ in a single function will give these two results for even and odd $n$ values?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that your conjecture is false.

Let $h(x)$ be a function given by the power series
$$h(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$
Assume that $h(x)$ is well defined, and that $h(1/2)=h(1)=h(2)=0$. (For example take $h(x)= (x-1/2)(x-1)(x-2)k(x)$ for a suitable $k(x)$).
For those $n$ such that $a_n\neq 0$, put $f(n)=(-1)^n/a_n$, and take $g(n)=2^{-n}$. Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{f(n)}g(n)=h(1/2)=0$$
and
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{f(n)}\frac{1}{g(n)}=h(2)=0$$
and also
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{f(n)}=h(1)=0$$